# Servlet 3.0 file upload (@MultipartConfig) with embedded jetty

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

When using jetty embedded, ie registering a servlet like this:

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", false, false);

s = new UploadServlet(jee);
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(s), "/upload");
```

Tthe MultipartConfig annotation does not seem to be respected. How do register URL's that support file upload under Servlet 3.0? Reverse engineering the Jetty code reveals it must be something like this, but what is the "multi"???

```
ServletHolder sh = new ServletHolder(new UploadServlet(jee));
Object multi;
sh.getRegistration().setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(multi));
context.addServlet(sh, "/upload");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `MultipartConfigElement` actually has multiple constructors. One takes an instance of a `MultipartConfig` annotation. The others take only the location or all the available options as parameters. So the easiest possiblity using all default will be

```
sh.getRegistration().setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacob,

Processing annotations with Jetty is currently only supported on WebAppContexts, and then also only if annotation processing is enabled. The jetty-9 doco talks about enabling annotations for a web app with stand-alone jetty here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/annotations.html

So, convert your ServletContextHandler to a WebAppContext, and call setConfigurationClasses() on it with the following list:

```
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration"
```

and make sure the annotation processing-related jars on your classpath - from the jetty distro these are:
javax.annotation-1.1.0.v201108011116.jar  org.objectweb.asm-3.1.0.v200803061910.jar

Jan

Comment: Thanks. I checked out the link in your post, but I couldn't see anything about "enabling" annotations for embedded jetty, only for standalone jetty.

Comment: @Jacob here's an [example of using Embedded Jetty with Servlet 3.0 Annotations](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0/blob/master/src/test/java/com/company/foo/EmbedMe.java).